# Is this syntax valid?

Tags: c#, syntax

I have a class in `C#` that has two constructors

```
public class GObject {

    public GObject(){
        // The default constructor
    }

    public GObject(int xPos, int yPos){
        // Second constructor
    }

}
```

Is this valid to write a sub-class `Block` like this?

```
public class Block : GObject {

    // Sub class methods go here, no special constructor

}
```

And instantiate `Block` with the 2<sup>nd</sup> constructor?

```
Block myBlock = new Block(10, 15);
```

Comment: Not valid. Have you tried to compile this code? You'll get an error: 'XYZ.Block' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

Comment: Just got a doubt since it worked with empty constructor, I thought it would call the constructor of the base class

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you don't have a two parameter constructor defined on `Block`, you can't write your final line - it will not compile.

You can have a chained constructor on `Block`:

```
public Block(int xPos, int yPos) : base(xPos, yPos)
{}
```

In which, case:

```
Block myBlock = new Block(10, 15);
```

Will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

By default, if you do not write the constructor explicitly; compiler creates a default constructor with no parameters.

In your case, since `Block` does not have any constructors defined, only parameterless constructor is created. Thus, you can not create a `Block` object using two parameters.